# Trying to make bot log something when a command is used discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make my bot where it will log an event aka a mod command when it's used. Since my bot is in multiple servers, i have a command where people can set the log channel that they want the bot to log events. So far, I have

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def setlogchannel(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
      with open('logchannel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        log_channel = json.load(fp)

      try:
        log_channel[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.id
      except KeyError:
        new = {str(ctx.guild.id): channel.id}
        log_channel.update(new)

      await ctx.send(f"Log Channel set to: `{channel}`!")

      with open('logchannel.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fpp:
        json.dump(log_channel, fpp, indent=2)
```

This is a command where people can set the log channel and this works fine when putting it into a .json file. But say for example, I want the bot to log when someone uses the `>clear` command. So far I have,

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):

      def log_channel(bot, channel):
        with open('logchannel.json', 'r') as fp:
          log_channel = json.load(fp)
          return log_channel[str(ctx.guild.id)]

      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Messages Cleared", description=f'{amount} messages were deleted!', color=0x00FFFF)
      author = ctx.message.author
      pfp = author.avatar_url
      embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=pfp)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
      log_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, id=log_channel[str(ctx.guild.id)])
      await log_channel.send(f"**{ctx.author.name}** cleared **{amount}** messages in the channel, **{ctx.channel.name}**!")
```

I have made some changes to see if any of them made it work, but the bot will not send the message to the log channel that was specifed. How can I get the log message to send? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are requesting the log channel seems to be wrong.

You actually have to open your `JSON` file again and look for `log_channel[str(ctx.guild.id)`.

**Here is an example on how it could work:**

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
        # Do what you want to do
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Test",
        description=f"{ctx.message.author} cleared {amount} messages".) # Your embed/msg
        with open('logchannel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            log_channel = json.load(fp)

        try:
            if log_channel:
                log_c = ctx.guild.get_channel(log_channel[str(ctx.guild.id)])
                await log_c.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

- I also built in some `except` statements if the channel was not found.

Comment: You can also handle two exceptions at the same time instead of having two separate `except` blocks, just `except (AttributeError, KeyError):`. Another thing would be to dedent the whole try/except block by one level, it's not really a good idea having the file opened that much time. Good answer tho!

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I changed my code and did both of those things :D

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński That's how it should be of course, you're right, probably a copy & paste error on my side, I will edit that!