# Trying to send welcome message in set welcome channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my python discord bot to send a welcome message in a certain channel when a member joins. My bot is in multiple servers so the channels are stored in a json file. In the on_member_join function, I define `get_wchannel` and `get_message` These two pull the certain channel and the message for that specific guild. Say a server wants it to say, `Welcome {member}! Glad your hear!` and the channel id is `845331373392003122` The bot will send that message to the channel id. One problem that I'm having is that whenever I try to send the message (which is in an embed) I get the following error in my console..

`await get_wchannel.send(embed=embed) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'`

My code is...

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
      def get_message(bot, message):
        with open('welcomemessage.json', 'r') as fp:
          get_message = json.load(fp)
      def get_wchannel(bot, message):
        with open('welcomechannel.json', 'r') as fp:
          get_wchannel = json.load(fp)
          try:
            return get_wchannel[str(message.guild.id)]
          except KeyError:
            return
      embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} joined!', description=f'{get_message}', color=0x00FFFF)
      embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      pfp = member.avatar_url
      embed.set_author(name=f"{member}", icon_url=pfp)
      memberpfp = member.avatar_url
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=memberpfp)
      try:
        if get_wchannel:
          await get_wchannel.send(embed=embed)
      except KeyError:
        return
```

How can I resolve this issue. Thanks! :D

Comment: I made an answer to something similar a while ago, is that helping you? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638343/trying-to-make-bot-log-something-when-a-command-is-used-discord-py/67638549#67638549) - You just need to change some things and should be good.

Answer (score 1):

`get_wchannel` is a function, you need to call it

```py
      try:
        if get_wchannel():
          await get_wchannel().send(embed=embed)
```

*PS: You don't need those arguments at all, you're not using them. Just remove them from the function definition or pass them when calling it*

Comment: I get this error.. `TypeError: get_wchannel() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'bot' and 'message'` I inserted those two but they were undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary arguments.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
      def get_message():
        with open('welcomemessage.json', 'r') as fp:
          get_message = json.load(fp)
      def get_wchannel(guild):
        with open('welcomechannel.json', 'r') as fp:
          get_wchannel = json.load(fp)
          try:
            return get_wchannel[str(guild.id)]
          except KeyError:
            return
      embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} joined!', description=get_message(), color=0x00FFFF)
      embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      pfp = member.avatar_url
      embed.set_author(name=f"{member}", icon_url=pfp)
      memberpfp = member.avatar_url
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=memberpfp)
      try:
        if get_wchannel(member.guild) is not None:
          await get_wchannel(member.guild).send(embed=embed)
      except KeyError:
        return
```

Comment: i get the error.. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'`

Comment: @ColeTMK Well I have no idea what `get_message` is supposed to do. And why are you reusing variable names? You do know that's bad practice, right? Are you new to Python or something?