# storing channel ids and guild ids with json python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, database, discord

**CODE**:

```
def get_channels(client, guild):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channelss = json.load(f)

    return channelss[str(guild.id)]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("testing...")


@client.command()
async def setreportchannel(ctx, channels: discord.TextChannel):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channel = json.load(f)

    channel[str(ctx.guild.id)] = int(channels.id)

    with open('channels.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(channel,f,indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f"set the report channel to {channels}")

@client.command()
async def report(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason):
    channel = client.get_channel(get_channels)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} has been reported for: {reason}")
```

**JSON FILE:**
{
"850356901232771082": 850357833538338816
}

**Problem:**
its not sending in the right channel on what is stored in the json file, its suppose to be in the place where the user set the channel with using the command setreportchannel

Comment: Is this helping you? [Trying to make bot log something when a command is used discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638343/trying-to-make-bot-log-something-when-a-command-is-used-discord-py/67638549#67638549)

Comment: yea, thank you, solved it thanks to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def get_channels(client, guild):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channelss = json.load(f)

    return channelss[str(guild.id)]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("testing...")


@client.command()
async def setreportchannel(ctx, channels: discord.TextChannel):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channelss = json.load(f)

    channelss[str(ctx.guild.id)] = int(channels.id)

    with open('channels.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(channelss,f,indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f"set the report channel to {channels}")

@client.command()
async def report(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason):
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channelss = json.load(f)


    channel_log = ctx.guild.get_channel(channelss[str(ctx.guild.id)])
    await channel_log.send(f"{member} has been reported for: {reason}")
```

so someone found it and helped me(not spoonfed)... the problem was the part on what I did at the channel logs wherein I put the channel id in it instead of the guild id